# Automatically Import Image into form from image URLs on the Web?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm using a form to upload wallpapers and we manually have to select a image file..I want to do this from a image URL ( image in the internet.. example- www.mysite.com/images/my.jpg ) ,it means without selecting a image file, I have a form like this -

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table class="grid" width="400">
        <tr class="r1">
            <td><label for="name">Title *:</label>      </td>
            <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $name?>" size="40" />      </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="r1">
            <td><label for="tags">Tags*:</label></td>
            <td><input name="tags" type="text" id="tags" value="<?php echo  View::escape($wallpaper->tags) ?>" size="40" />      </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="r1">
            <td><label for="img">Wallpaper*:</label></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="img" id="img" />      </td>
        </tr>


            <td><input type="submit" name="upload_wallpaper" id="upload_wallpaper" value="Submit" />

        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Now i want to load image via a URL on this section of the form -

```
    <tr class="r1">
        <td><label for="img">Wallpaper*:</label></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="img" id="img" />      </td>
    </tr>
```

After that i'll manually submit the form after that..i just want to upload via url by entering URL like **www.mysite.com/images/my.jpg ** without selecting browse and select a image file.. I tried alot but i failed to find a solution..thank you!!! Anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the input type from file to a text box. Then on the backend, use curl or something similar to download the image file that was input (if it exists).

```
if (isset($_POST['img'])) {
    $url = $_POST['img'];

    // Curl the URL
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    // Save it to disk
    $savePath = "/somewhere-on-your-disk/filename.jpg";
    $fp = fopen($savePath,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $result);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Yeah i tried     <input name="img" type="text" id="img" value="" size="40" />  Like this...but its not working..btw how to do this in curl? can you help me?

Comment: I have edited my answer.. But you should add some error checking too. Make sure the file exists before trying to save it to disk