# Upload image by directly entering a image URL?

Tags: html

I have used a input file code to upload image to my wallpaper site..

```
    <input type="file" name="img" id="img" />
```

Is there anyway to select a image without selecting image file..like entering URL to text box?

```
    <input name="img" type="text" id="img" value="http://www.somesite.com/image.my.jpg" size="40" />
```

I tried its not working...please help me! Anyway to enter image url to text box  except select browse button and selecting image file? help me i tries in different ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add support for this on 'somesite.com'. This is not something you can solve with HTML, it needs to be solved on the server-side.

Comment: no no i just want to enter URL and upload that image in mysite.com to my wallpaper site...full form is here Evert. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969045/automatically-import-image-into-form-from-image-urls-on-the-web

Comment: Well the answer there was to use curl. What have you tried on the server side (and I actually meant your wallpaper site, not 'somesite.com' in the example, sorry).

Comment: How to do that? I'm new to php? can you help me..I'll do rest alone..can you help me?

Comment: Close this question and ask a new question. Something like.. "How can I download an image based on a url in PHP". Make sure you at least tried something..